# PHP: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd': undefinied symbol only in CLI

Tags: php, mysqli

I am unable to get mysql related functions to work with PHP in command line, everything works just fine on the apache webserver, even PHPmyAdmin works perfectly.

Operating system: Debian 11

PHP Version: 8.2

This what happens when I run `php -v`

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqlnd' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqlnd (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqlnd: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), 
/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqlnd.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqlnd.so: undefined symbol: EVP_PKEY_CTX_new)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mysqli' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), 
/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/mysqli.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_global_stats)) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_mysql (/usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_mysql: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), 
/usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20220829/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_get_client_info)) in Unknown on line 0
```

My original issue was the mysqli class not found, after investigation I found that php.ini for the cli was not /etc/php/8.2/cli/php.ini I been editing but instead it was trying to load a non existant php.ini in /usr/local/lib/. Once I fixed that issue the above errors started showing up.

Running `phpinfo();` in an apache script and `php -i` shows they are both the same version of PHP (with the same version of Zend Engine) and loading the extensions from the same folder (/usr/lib/php/20220829)

I tried uninstalling PHP entirely (originally installed from source) and reinstalling it with `apt` - same errors

Also tried putting `extension=mysqlnd` before `extension=mysqli` in the php.ini file and that made no difference, also makes no difference if they are commented out or not.

Comment: Order is probably problem here.  About "makes no difference if they are commented out" then you probably do it in wrong .ini Try this `php -i |grep php\.ini` to find correct ini

Comment: It looks like your system might be set up with multiple versions of PHP, and it looks like whichever version of PHP you're executing is trying to load extensions that were built for a different version. Undo the changes you've made to your configuration and refer to the docs of whatever you've been using to install parallel PHP versions as to how to install extensions for certain versions/installations.

Comment: @Sergey92zp you were right, I was looking at the wrong one. So commenting extensions out does make a difference. But the current order is mysqlnd > mysqli > pdo_mysql.

Comment: @Sammitch I am not trying to install parallel PHP versions, and both ‘phpinfo()’ thru Apache and ‘php -v’ thru CLI both output I am running v8.2.6 of PHP

Comment: first error looks like ssl dependency, try to apt-get install php8.2-openssl

Comment: @Sergey92zp I think you are right, running ‘php -i | grep -i openssl’ says it’s disabled. Unfortunately trying apt-get install php8.2-openssl was unsuccessful because it cannot find the package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Sergey92zp for pointing me in the right direction.

OpenSSL wasn’t loading when PHP was executed through the CLI. I wasn’t able to install `php8.2-OpenSSL` through apt. But I was able to compile the “OpenSSL.so” extension by the source. After that it needs to be enabled first in php.ini. So extension order would be: openssl > mysqlnd > mysqli > pdo_mysql